# Catch FaultException<TDetail> for any Exception derived TDetail?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, faultexception

How do I catch FaultException for any Exception derived TDetail?
I tried `catch( FaultException<Exception> ) {}` but that does not seem to work.

**Edit**
The purpose is to gain access to the Detail property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FaultException<>` inherits from `FaultException`.  So change your code to:

```
catch (FaultException fx)  // catches all your fault exceptions
{
    ...
}
```

**=== Edit ===**

If you need `FaultException<T>.Detail`, you've a couple of options but none of them are friendly.  The best solution is to catch each individual type you want to catch:

```
catch (FaultException<Foo> fx) 
{
    ...
}
catch (FaultException<Bar> fx) 
{
    ...
}
catch (FaultException fx)  // catches all your other fault exceptions
{
    ...
}
```

I advise you do it like that.  Otherwise, you're going to dip into reflection.

```
try
{
    throw new FaultException<int>(5);
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    Type exType = ex.GetType();
    if (exType.IsGenericType && exType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(FaultException<>)))
    {
        object o = exType.GetProperty("Detail").GetValue(ex, null);
    }
}
```

Reflection is slow, but since exceptions are supposed to be rare...  again, I advise breaking them out as you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (FaultException ex) 
{
    MessageFault fault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
    var objFaultContract = fault.GetDetail<Exception>();

    //you will get all attributes in objFaultContract
}
```